# Cannot scrape using python.requests() but work when loading on browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to scrape data from this page: https://raritysniffer.com/viewcollection/primeapeplanet

The API request works on the browser but returns 403 ERROR when I use python.requests.

```
requests.get("https://raritysniffer.com/api/index.php?query=fetch&collection=0x6632a9d63e142f17a668064d41a21193b49b41a0&taskId=any&norm=true&partial=true&traitCount=true")
```

I understand it is possible that I have to pass on specific headers to make it work, but as a python novice, I have no idea how to make it work. Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you check the response, you can see that the website uses Cloudfare and which indeed returns the 403. To bypass this, try [cloudscraper](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/VeNoMouS-cloudscraper-python-web-crawling). (be mindful)

```
import cloudscraper
    
url = 'https://raritysniffer.com/api/index.php?query=fetch&collection=0x6632a9d63e142f17a668064d41a21193b49b41a0&taskId=any&norm=true&partial=true&traitCount=true'

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(browser = 'firefox')
print(scraper.get(url).text)
```